# Nginx reverse proxy getting 400 error bad request

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set up nginx as reverse proxy to an application.
When I set up the same request over http it works fine

I think I've done everything and I still have the 400 error. Any help will be really nice.

My nginx configuration file :

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

    client_max_body_size 10M;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My site configuration :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location /eai {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.44.128:8000;
    }
}
server {
    listen               443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/certificates/myssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certificates/myssl.key;
    server_name example.com;
    location /eai {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.44.128:8000;
    }
}
```

My python code to call the application behind the proxy :

```
import requests

url = 'https://example.com/eai/request/import'
file_list = [
    ('file', ('test.csv', open('test.csv', 'rb'), 'text/html')),
]

r = requests.post(url, files=file_list, proxies={"https":"https://192.168.44.241","http":"http://192.168.44.241"}, verify=False)
```

The info line in the error.log

```
client sent invalid request while reading client request line, client: 192.168.44.1, server: example.com, request: "CONNECT example.com:443 HTTP/1.0"
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:

```
proxies={"https":"https://192.168.44.241","http":"http://192.168.44.241"}
```

Your client connection is not actually going through a proxy, so this should not be present at all. You are just making a normal HTTPS request to a normal HTTPS server.